# My UK visa issued in maiden name passport

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

My UK visitors visa was issued in my passport which has my maiden name. My flight was booked for last night and, as I arrived at the home affairs counter (immigration) at the airport, they said that my passport was reported stolen, that I cannot travel, and also that I should obtain new passport with my married name on it.

I never reported my passport stolen, but it is on record. What do I have to do now? Can they transfer my visa to my new passport? How do I do that and what is the cost involved?

Comment: You should ask the UK consulate whether you can use your old visa.  If you passport were merely expired, or replaced because it was full, your old visa would still be valid.  But since the passport was reported stolen, the status of the visa might be different.  If you can use the old visa, you'll want to bring a copy of your marriage certificate as proof of your name change.

Comment: You should find out every detail about how and who reported your passport 'stolen'. There's no point in getting another one issued if somebody is just going to come along and invalidate it with a false report. Make them show you the police report. Many consulates won't accept a report of a stolen passport without a police report. Find out exactly what happened.